# How to make qpOASES do not show the iteration details during solution

Tags: quadratic-programming

I want to apply qpOASES in C++ on visual studio 2015 to solve the quadratic programming problem. But the iteration details such "Step size" will be shwon. How can I make the qpOASES silence?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `PrintLevel` to `PL_NONE` or `PL_LOW`. See the documentation at https://www.coin-or.org/qpOASES/doc/3.2/manual.pdf.

Comment: I have got the answer in the document and thkx any way